# Rule Designer 8.9.2 error when trying to install maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, ibm-odm

I am working with ODM Rule Designer 8.9.2.
I want to install the maven plugin but are not able to due to connection error message.

As there is no marketplace in Rule Designer, I am trying to use the Install New Software function with the following site:
http://download.Eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/latest

I have tried to change the network setting options as some solutions suggest, but doesnt work.
I have tried to amend the .ini file solution i found here on this site, but that just gives a different connection error then.

[image: The error message I get]

I have done a lot of searching and cannot find an answer to this, hoping someone out there has faced and solved this one!